# How do I do a loop while a condition is equal to another condition with an exception?

Tags: do-while

While the member enrollment month is equal to the provider effective month I want to pull the assignedprovider1 for the maximum provider effective month for that member but if the enrollment month doesn't find a provider effective month keep the assignedprovider1 for the last one you pulled and keep it throughout the enrollment months going forward.

```
TABLE 1
MemberNbr   ENROLLMENT_MONTH    Desired Outcome ProviderEffectiveDate
ABCD            1/1/2019            A203            20190110
ABCD            2/1/2019            A015            20190208
ABCD            3/1/2019            A015            20190208
ABCD            4/1/2019            A015            20190208
ABCD            5/1/2019            A015            20190208
ABCD            6/1/2019            A015            20190208
ABCD            7/1/2019            A015            20190208
ABCD            8/1/2019            A015            20190208


TABLE 2         
AssignedProvider1   ProviderEffectiveDate   MemberNbr   
A018                    20190108            ABCD    
A203                    20190110            ABCD    
A046                    20190205            ABCD    
A015                    20190208            ABCD
```

I tried doing a while loop within a while loop but couldn't get it to work and I tried using rank but couldn't figure out how to add the other piece.

```
select F.MEMBERNBR, F.ELIGIBILITYSTARTDATE, P.PROVIDEREFFECTIVEDATE, P.ASSIGNEDPROVIDER1
INTO #HELPMELORD
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PROVIDEREFFECTIVEDATE, P.ASSIGNEDPROVIDER1, P.MEMBERNBR, F.ELIGIBILITYSTARTDATE ORDER BY P.PROVIDEREFFECTIVEDATE DESC) AS 'RANK'
FROM #FINAL F
LEFT JOIN MEMBERPROVIDERHISTORY P ON F.MEMBERNBR = P.MEMBERNBR
```

I don't have any output to show because I can't get it to work.

Comment: You refer to a do-while loop, but this looks like sql, so I'm not sure what language or system you're doing the do-while in. Please clarify :)

Comment: Yes it is sql.  I was trying to do a While.